# react read data after setData

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const useCustomState = () => [value, setValue];
const [data, setData] = useCustomState(initValue);
useEffect(() => {
   const fn = async() => {
       await setData(1);
       console.log(data); // ouput 1
   };
   fn();
}, [])
```

How to implement this custom hooks function can get the latest value of data immediately after setting data in async syntax. I know it should be done by useEffect(() => console.log(data), [data]). But the useEffect all over the floor looks very inelegant

Comment: Can you be more specific, what exactly your custom hook is doing and what values is returning? 
What do you mean by setting data in async syntax? 
Write a more detailed explanation what the hook supposed to do and what you are trying to acheive

Comment: You would need to add the state in your useEffect that way the component where you are using can re-render after the initial time. Otherwise it will still do all the re-initialization without changing the return value

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan
I hope that the custom hook can replace the original useState to take over the state of the component, and hope that the data can be updated at any time after using the custom hook, and the updated value can be read at any time. I know that when the component does not trigger rendering, the data of the component will not be updated, so the latest state data cannot be read.
The purpose of this is to hope that the business logic of the components is continuous and changes with the order in which the code is written. For example, the code is as follows:

Comment: ```const comp = function() {
       const[data, setData] = useCustomState(0);
       const updateBusiness1 = function() {
               set data(1)
        }
       const updateBusiness2 = function() {
              if (data > 0) {
                  // do something
              }
       }
       const ButtonClickHandler = async function() {
           await update business 1()
           await update business 2()
       }
}```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom useState hook as you desired.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';

const useCustomState = (initValue) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initValue);
  const cbRef = useRef();

  const SetState = useCallback((newState, cb) => {
    cbRef.current = cb
    setState(newState);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state);
      cbRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [state]);

  return [state, SetState];
}
```

You can use this in your component like this as you wished:

```
const [data, setData] = useCustomState(initValue);

useEffect(() => {
  const fn = async() => {
    await setData(1, newData => {
      console.log(newData); // output 1
    });
  };
  fn();
}, []);
```

Plese read more about how to create custom hooks [here](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) and legacy features [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

You should remember that using a custom hook would still not eliminate the execution of `useEffect` since the components are asynchronous and depends on re-render cycle.

Another option to get the value of without creating a custom hook is by calling another `useEffect` in the same component which would fire upon any changes to the targeted state or prop.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(initValue);

useEffect(() => {
   const fn = async() => {
       await setData(1);
   };
   fn();
}, []);

useEffect(() => { //<---- Call another useEffect
   console.log(data); //<--- Here, it would show the result
}, [data]); //<---- Listen to data changes
```

Comment: This is just extra code without any benefits I guess

Comment: @innocent Without any benefits? I take that critisim as a friendly feedback. To immediately get the result from the default useState is not possible thus a custom hook with a ref would be needed to have immediate access to the value. The custom hook could also be used to distinguish different business logic and respective behaviour.

Comment: i meant no disrespect but for the custom hook to work in this scenario you would still need to put it inside the useEffect inside the component's useEffect which is what will cause it to trigger the re-render or changes like I commented in the OP's question comment

Comment: It's communicating and exchanging information, nothing disrespect about that :) But you must know that whatever method you employ, the typical pattern of responding to state changes with useEffect in the component is still necessary. Any custom hook wouldn't change that. But it does provide you with an immediate value which you otherwise wouldn't get... (Unless you subscribe to the state handler for immediate result which is a whole different aspect)

Comment: I think it makes sense for many people to spend a lot of time developing async so that asynchronous code can look like synchronous writing, but react's useEffect design makes asynchronous operations return to callback hell. This design is not friendly, and it is hoped to save this phenomenon by customizing the hooks syntax.

Comment: Why is await setState('new value'); instead of setState('new value', (newValue) => console.log(newValue)); because it must insert subsequent code sentences for state into setState in the form of a function parameter. This is not a good programming practice and it will increase maintenance costs.
If my idea can be realized, in scenarios with low performance requirements, this custom function will present component logic changes more naturally

Comment: @yakiler I see where you're coming from. The challenge is that React's state updates are inherently asynchron and batched for performance reasons. There's no built-in way to wait for a state update to complete because React manages state updates and re-renders in an optimized way. If you want to different way to manage your states, you might consider using a different strategy which doesn't rely on React's state.

Comment: @knoxgon Probably this is not easy to achieve, in current react version design